# Cannot get camera / lamp aligned after importing DXF file

Tags: 3d-view, file-format

I have imported a DXF file in a new scene. When I add a sun lamp and a camera I cannot get them aligned. This imported 3D model has a scale of millimeters. I will attach the blend file

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your dxf imported objects are by far too large, look how they compare to the blender grid!

[image]

If you select all them and scale them by 0.01 they almost fit again in the blender grid...

[image]

like this

[image]

now you can add a plane, a sun lamp and a camera and use them correctly

[image]

**edit**: expanding the answer to follow comments request.

I guess opening a new specific question would be better, but: dimensions are relative to the scene units and scale.

Try this: select a sample mesh (eg: a door panel) go into edit mode, select only a vertical front door edge (it should be around 2 meters). Now in the properties panel (N key) under "mesh display", enable "edge info: length".

if units are "none" what length does the edge show?

[image]

and what if units are "metric"?

[image]

that door is too high...

You can adjust to the right measure either

1. scaling the whole mesh accordingly (try scaling 0.01, and apply scaling)
2. scaling the scene metric units by the same amount (both will make your model sized more like the blender grid)

eg: method 2

[image]

I hope this help more...

Comment: I am struggling with scale and dimensions. The imported 3D model is in millimeters. How should I set the unit settings ?

Comment: opening your file I see no specific unit preset ("length" is "none", it should mean it is in "blender units", see https://www.blender.org/manual/en/data_system/scenes/properties.html). Do you need specifically a conventional units system? What are you struggling with? DXF import oprions can allow you to specify a "unit scale"...

Comment: the 3d model was created in formZ and exported as a DXF file. The model was in millimeters. Should I have set units = millimeters and length = metric and when importing the DXF file the unit scale at 0.001 ?

Comment: It could depend on what you need to to later... open a specific question, to get more help...

Comment: If I follow up your advice everything works. But I still don't understand things .... the model was designed in millimeters. Therefore when I imported the file I set the unit scale converter factor at 0.001. Why have I to scale down the model after importing ?

Comment: I've just edited the answer, to add further details...